# Error in Passing 2d Array in C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, graph

I am getting the error:

Cannot convert int** to int*[5]...

in my code. I know how to pass 2 D arrays to functions but I am stuck here.

The code is intended for Depth first Traversal over a Adjacency Matrix.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

#define m 5
#define n 5

void dfs(int G[][n],int i,int visited[])
{
     visited[i]=1;
     int j;
     for(j=0;j<n;j++)
     {
         if(!visited[j]&&G[i][j]==1)
                     dfs(G,j,visited);
     }
}

int main()
{   int r,c,i;
    printf("Enter Dimensions\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&r,&c);
    r = m; c = n;
    int **G = (int **)malloc(r*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        G[i] = (int *)malloc(c*sizeof(int));
    }
    printf("Enter the Matrix\n");
    int j;

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
          scanf("%d",G[i][j]);
    int *visited = (int*)malloc(r*sizeof(int));
    memset(visited,0,sizeof(visited));

    dfs(G,0,visited);

}
```

Comment: In c++, use `std::vector`.

Comment: change `void dfs(int G[][n],int i,int visited[])` to `void dfs(int* G[],int i,int visited[])`

Comment: `memset(visited, 0, sizeof(visited))` is wrong, `scanf("%d", G[i][j])` too. Also what are you reading `r` and `c` for?

Comment: do not cast return value of `malloc()`. also, `c++` has `new`. make use of that.

Comment: @iharob I was trying to take dimensions from the user but it didn't work so I took macros

Comment: Choose your language C or C++.

Comment: @Jarod42 C++ but I am more or less using C here

Comment: @edbale No, you're not. If you're compiling it with a C++ compiler there are differences, some significant. If you want to program in C use a C compiler, don't simply treat C++ as _C with classes_ because it's _not_.

Comment: While they can often be used in the same way, `x[n]` and `*x` are not the same thing. I think if you change your `G[][]` to `**G` in the function signature, you should be okay. The distinction is that `x[n]` is an array, and passing it to a function would pass all the elements of the array on the stack. Passing `*x` to a function simply passes the pointer, which is far more efficient.

Comment: Just a quick rant to all of the commenters trying to tell the OP to avoid C idioms in C++. C++ is -- by definition -- a superset of C. It incorporates all of standard C in its own standard. There is nothing wrong with using `malloc()` and `printf()` and other C standard idioms in C++. It's common, correct, and often very efficient. It's always a good idea to know what you're doing, but blindly preferring `new` over `malloc()` is no better than blindly preferring `malloc()` over `new`. Know your tools and choose the one that works best in the context of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is this, it is a c solution, if you want c++ you should probably use `std::vector` instead.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;


void dfs(int **G, int i, int *visited, int c)
{
    int j;

    visited[i] = 1;
    for(j = 0 ; j < c ; j++)
    {
        if((visited[j] == 0) && (G[i][j] == 1))
            dfs(G, j, visited, c);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int   r, c, i, j;
    int **G;
    int  *visited;

    printf("Enter Dimensions\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &r, &c);

    G = malloc(r * sizeof(*G));
    if (G == NULL)
        return -1;
    visited = malloc(r * sizeof(*visited));
    if (visited == NULL)
    {
        free(G);
        return -1;
    }
    memset(visited, 0, r * sizeof(*visited));

    printf("Enter the Matrix\n");
    for(i = 0 ; i < r ; i++)
    {
        G[i] = malloc(c * sizeof(**G));
        if (G[i] == NULL)
        {
            for (j = i - 1 ; j >= 0 ; --j)
                free(G[j]);
            free(G);

            return -1;
        }
        for(j = 0 ; j < c ; j++)
            scanf("%d", &(G[i][j]));
    }
    dfs(G, 0, visited, c);

    /* now free */
    free(visited);
    for(i = 0 ; i < r ; i++)
        free(G[i]);
    free(G);

    return 0;
}
```

this could also be a c++ solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

void dfs(int **G, int i, int *visited, int c)
{
    int j;

    visited[i] = 1;
    for(j = 0 ; j < c ; j++)
    {
        if((visited[j] == 0) && (G[i][j] == 1))
            dfs(G, j, visited, c);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int   r, c, i, j;
    int **G;
    int  *visited;

    printf("Enter Dimensions\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &r, &c);

    G       = new int*[r];
    visited = new int[r];

    memset(visited, 0, r * sizeof(*visited));

    printf("Enter the Matrix\n");
    for(i = 0 ; i < r ; i++)
    {
        G[i] = new int[c];
        for(j = 0 ; j < c ; j++)
            scanf("%d", &(G[i][j]));
    }
    dfs(G, 0, visited, c);

    /* now free */
    delete[] visited;
    for(i = 0 ; i < r ; i++)
        delete[] G[i];
    delete[] G;

    return 0;
}
```

And finally with `std::vector`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
void dfs(const vector< vector<int> > &G, int i, vector<int> &visited)
{
    size_t j;

    visited[i] = 1;
    for(j = 0 ; j < visited.size() ; j++)
    {
        if((visited[j] == 0) && (G[i][j] == 1))
            dfs(G, j, visited);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int r, c, i, j;


    printf("Enter Dimensions\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &r, &c);

    vector< vector<int> > G(r, vector<int>(c));
    vector<int>           visited(r, 0);

    printf("Enter the Matrix\n");
    for(i = 0 ; i < r ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < c ; j++)
            scanf("%d", &(G[i][j]));
    }
    dfs(G, 0, visited);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think error part is function definition :

You should write it as following :

```
void dfs(int *G[],int i,int visited[])
```

Rather than giving value to second dimension, you should keep it as shown.

Or you can also write it like :

```
void dfs(int **G,int i,int *visited)
```

Everything else is fine.