# Error in Passing 2d array as function argument in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, 2d

I am trying to pass 2d array to a function but the compiler shows error :

error: cannot convert `int (*)[5]` to `int**` for argument `1` to `int max_size(int**, int, int)`

I know the theory but can not figure out why it is not working.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

#define r 6
#define c 5

using namespace std;

int max_size(int *g[],int m,int n)
{
    // Initial Structure for DP
    int i,j;
    int **s = (int **) malloc (r*sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        s[i]=(int *)malloc(c*sizeof(int));
    memset(s,0,sizeof(s));

    // Initialization for DP
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        s[i][0] = g[i][0];
    for(i=0;i<c;i++)
        s[0][i] = g[0][i];

    // Formulation for DP

    for(i=1;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<c;j++)
        {
            if(g[i][j])

                s[i][j]= min(s[i-1][j],s[i-1][j-1],s[i][j-1])+1;

            else
                s[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    int c = 0;

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            if(s[i][j]>c) c=s[i][j];
        }
    }

return c;
}


int main()
{
   int m[r][c] = {{1,0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0,1},{1,1,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,1}};
   cout<<max_size(m,r,c);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: `std::cout` vs `malloc`...

Comment: @Jarod42 fair point.

Comment: You asked the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27725160/1983495) twice? why? [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27725366/1983495) is the answer I gave you, i think it's a good answer.

Comment: @iharob One more help, expected unqualified-id before numeric constant in the line int c =0; Why is the error coming, I tried to search but couldn't get it corrected.

Comment: because `c` is a macro, you can't declare a variable with that name nor can you assign to `c` since macros are replaced by the preprocessor at compile time, the faulty line is replace with `int 5 = 0;` so you see why the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to pass a 2D array as an argument of type `int**`. That conversion is not possible, because they would have fundamentally different structures.

A 2D array (3x3 for example) looks like this in memory:

```
  0,0   0,1   0,2   1,0   1,1   1,2   2,0   2,1   2,2
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

A `int**` when used as a kind of 2D array (where the outermost pointer points at the first element in an array of pointers, and each of those points to the first element in an array of ints) looks like this:

```
┌─────┐
│     │ // The int**
└──╂──┘
   ┃
   ▼
┌─────┬─────┬┄
│     │     │   // An array of int*
└──╂──┴──╂──┴┄
   ┃     ┗━━━━━━━━━━┓
   ▼                ▼
┌─────┬─────┬┄   ┌─────┬─────┬┄
│ int │ int │    │ int │ int │    // Arrays of ints
└─────┴─────┴┄   └─────┴─────┴┄
  0,0   0,1        1,0   1,1
```

However, a 2D array of type `int[x][y]` is convertible to type `int(*)[y]` (this is called array-to-pointer conversion in general), so you could write your function like so:

```
int max_size(int (*g)[c],int m,int n);
```

This can alternatively be written with some syntactic sugar like so:

```
int max_size(int g[][c],int m,int n);
```

Parameters of array type (like this one) are transformed to pointers - that is, the `[]` really doesn't say "array" at all. In fact, you can put a size in those brackets but it will be completely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain you have to declare the size of your array in your function declarations and initializations.

`int max_size(int *g[]` should be `int max_size(int *g[5]` or whatever the size of the array should be.

Comment: I am not sure of this, what is wrong with passing a pointer to pointer.

Comment: @edbale They aren't pointers, but array declarations. There's a difference!

Comment: `int *g[]` is exactly the same as `int *g[5]` in C++

Comment: And they're both the same as `int** g` (clarification: *as function parameter types*), which is what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
int max_size(int *g[],int m,int n)
```

To

```
int max_size(int g[][c],int m,int n)
```

Comment: You're omitting the wrong dimension. You can only omit the first dimension.

Answer (score 0):

`int a[6][5];` defines a single array of memory that supports syntax for a stride length.

`int * a[]` and `int ** a` don't a provide stride length (or row or column size depending on how you want to think about it) and define an array of pointers to other memory, not a single block of memory like `int a[6][5];` does.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain ways to do it

**1) When second dimension is available globally** (either as a macro or as a global constant).

```
int max_size(int g[][c],int m,int n)
```

**2) Using a single pointer**

```
void max_size(int *g, int m, int n) and call it as
max_size((int *)m,r,c)
```

**3) Using an array of pointers or double pointer**

```
void max_size(int *g[], int m, int n) and call it as

max_size((int **)m,r,c)
```

Any of them will work.Its just how you want to use.