# Error in Traversing Matrix in C

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

The Error comment mentioned in the below code is where the program stops working.
I am not sure what is the error. Please help. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int print(int *g[],int m,int n)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("Check\n");
            printf("%d\t",g[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int i,r,c,j;
    printf("Enter Matrix Row\n");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("Enter Matrix Column\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);

    int **s=(int **)malloc(r*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        s[i]=(int*)malloc(c*sizeof(int));

    memset(s,0,sizeof(s));

    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("I will Win\n");

            // Here is the Error

            printf("%d\t",s[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    //cout<<print((int**)s,r,c);

}
```

I think memset should work here. 
Inside the function also traversal is not working.

Comment: You tagged this as `C++`, but little to no C++ is used.  It's all `C`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie see the includes.

Comment: Why are you mixing c and c++ code in such a horrible way in first place?

Comment: In c++ you should use `new[]` and not `malloc`. Also there exists `free` too, and in the case of `new[]` `delete[]`.

Comment: @iharob - One include is not necessary.  The others have equivalents in 'C'.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27725160/1983495)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I read that printf and scanf and C functions are faster than C++ cout ..etc. And I write them in C++ so that if need be I can use STL. I read this in some competitive programming blog. Is it wrong?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's wrong, you should use c++ as c++ and not as if it was c, for that use c instead.

Comment: @edbale _"Is it wrong? "_ Yes that's blatantly wrong, and you should just put that source of information to your paper bin.

Comment: @edbale - In addition to all of that, you have memory leaks.  And if you want speed, the way you allocated the 2-d array is slow if `r` is large.  All you need are two calls to `malloc` and a loop, not `r` calls to `malloc` within the loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How to allocate it faster ? And please please tell me where are the memory leaks and what can I do to prevent them ? Thanks a lot. Please give any sources or links where I can learn these concepts of memory leak, faster allocation.

Comment: @edbale - You can start here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425126/dynamic-allocation-of-two-dimensional-array-c/27425293#27425293  The answer speaks of `new[]` and `delete[]`, but also applies to `malloc` and `free`.  You allocate the row pointers(which you did), but you should allocate *all* the data with a single call to `malloc`.  Then the loop is written to set the row pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memset()` sets all the bits to `0`, in your case you are making all the pointers in `s` `NULL`. Almost because `sizeof(s)` is the size of a pointer not the count of pointers in the array of pointers.

If What you need is to initialize to zero this should do it

```
int **s=(int **)calloc(r, sizeof(int*));
for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    s[i]=(int*)calloc(c, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Thanks again. When the 2d array here is passed to the function, it is passed by copy , right? To pass by reference I have to use a pointer to 2d array, right? Could you please tell me how to pass it by reference. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, a pointer is passed. You don't need to pass by reference. You pass a pointer to the same data of the passed array.

Comment: Yes I got it. A pointer is passed if the argument is itself a pointer both in the case of 2d and 1d array. So, no need to pass by reference. If we have to modify the pointer itself (not only its contents) then only we need one more level of indirection. Like if I had to delete the 2d array then I can't pass it like I did it here. How to pass the 2d array to a function which would delete it ? Last help, thanks a lot more.

Comment: @edbale Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Maybe when I want to delete a graph which is represented as matrix. I am frightened of compilation errors in this case. Everytime I am with 2d arrays I get some compilation error.

Comment: I think you are confusing one delete with another. The c++ `delete[]` operator just free's the allocated memory back to the operating system, it has nothing to do with deleting a graph. That should go in your design.